# What is needed to be done for sorting by date?

Tags: java

I need to sort the status reports by date. Before I'm calling the addItem method the sorting should be done or I have to compare with previous report by report date. It is to be stated that the getReportDate()[ which is of type JVDate] method can be used to get the report date of a status report. Would you please help to sort the status reports:

```
   public void  doImport( TRDataReader in )
        throws IOException, TRException        
   {

       in.start( getClassTag() ); // get the class tag
       // import the set's flags from a datareader
       importFlags( in ); 
       beginLoad ();
       final String restag = new TRStatusReport().getClassTag ();
       while (in.nextToken (restag))  {
             addItem (new TRStatusReport (in));
       }
       endLoad ();
       in.end (getClassTag ());
   }
```

Comment: What is a `JVDate`? Does it implement `Comparable`?

Comment: What are you sorting?  An array?  A `List`?  Where is the declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Java's built-in sorting algorithm, by specifying the appropriate comparator.  Something like to following:

```
public void  doImport(TRDataReader in) throws IOException, TRException {
    in.start(getClassTag()); // get the class tag
    importFlags(in); // import the set's flags from a datareader

    // Add the reports to a temporary list first.
    final String restag = new TRStatusReport().getClassTag();
    List<TRStatusReport> list = new ArrayList<TRStatusReport>();
    while (in.nextToken(restag)) {
        list.add(new TRStatusReport(in));
    }         

    // Now sort them.
    TRStatusReport[] array = list.toArray(new TRStatusReport[]{});
    Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<TRStatusReport>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TRStatusReport o1, TRStatusReport o2) {
            return o1.getReportDate().compareTo(o2.getReportDate());
        }
    });

    // Add it to the internal list.
    beginLoad();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        addItem(array[i]);
    }
    endLoad();
    in.end( getClassTag() );
}
```

You will have to find a way to compare the dates if they are not Java Date objects.  I've written this code blindly (I don't know what the objects are) and with some assumptions.  For example, the beginLoad() and endLoad() methods... are they for the list or for the reading? ...if so, they may need to be placed around the while clause where the objects are loaded and added to the temporary list.

Comment: Can you be more specific? ...if it was the compare that should be compareTo, I've fixed that.  The above is not suppose to be a copy and paste... some tinkering may be required. :)

Comment: @jaco would you please tell where should i used the code section and should i remove addItem method? and also it is showing that reportList can be resolved to a variable. Also showing The method compareTo(JVDate) is undefined for the type JVDate.

Comment: @jack the toArray, sort and compareTo methods are not working . The errors are as follows:1.The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<TRStatusReport> is not applicable for the arguments (TRStatusReport) 2.The method compareTo(JVDate) is undefined for the type JVDate 3.The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (TRStatusReport[], new Comparator<TRStatusReport>(){})

Comment: I've fixed the toArray - yes silly mistake.  I don't know how to compare the JVDate (it's not a standard Java class).  Assuming that it is a wrapper of some sorts, something like o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate()) may work.  Someone else edit and broke my code by replacing the array with a list in the sort call (which I've fixed previously).  Make sure it says "array" and not "reportList" or "list".

Comment: sort and comapareTo method still not working: A JVDate object can be declared like : JVDate latest = TR_DATE_NULL;

Comment: Which getters are defined on JVDate?

Comment: Should i give you class JVDate or the name of the instance variables?

Comment: I recommend that you read up on Java a bit and give this problem some thought.  The help I've provided is enough to get you going. Inside the JVDate there must be some getter (i.e. getDate(), getTime()) that will allow you to compare.  Make sure the sort definition is like I've provided at the top. Good luck.

Comment: I have created a new getter in JVDate class and now the problem for compareTo method is over. But the error for sort method is not solved yet. Please can you help me regarding this error:.The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<TRStatusReport> is not applicable for the arguments (TRStatusReport)

Comment: TRStatusReport[] array = list.toArray(new TRStatusReport[]{});  Are you sure the line looks like this in your code? Are you sure the error is on this line? Let me know, we can have this sorted soon. :)